# Databases,RAM and rerformance

Tags: database, mongodb, performance, ram

I have 5GB dictionary, where key is word and value is 300d vector of numbers but I have only 1GB RAM (minus 200MB of server) and 50GB ssd. My goal is relatively fast (1-3sec) retrieval of vector, for every word in input sentence.

What kind of storage system would be best for this kind of task? Is a nonsql database like Mongo a good option?

If so, is there a way to calculate minimal cache memory that will mongo need, and is this solution feasible with given hardware?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming single precision float number with `32` bits each and `32` bit `word` keys, `5GB` roughly sums up to `4.1` million vectors.

You could store a `<word, word>` dictionary with these `4.1` million entries in `RAM`. The value part of the dictionary points to a combination of file and offset within the file stored on `SSD`. In case your assumptions are different, the calculation should stay similar.

It is probably not practical to store the whole vectors in a single file. It might be sufficient to store the vectors in a database, provided the tablespace reside on SSD.

**Example:** You could have `32` files with `130.000` vectors each. Then, the highest `5` bits of the word value indicate the file, and the lowest `27` bits are the offset or vector number within the file.